# minimizing portfolio tracking error yield unlogical results

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, portfolio

I have a `pd.DataFrame` with daily stock returns of shape `(250,10)` and a `pd.Series` with my benchmarks daily returns of shape `(250,)`. The goal is to minimize the Tracking Error, between a portfolio of stocks and the benchmark.
The tracking error is the Standard Deviation of (Portfolio - Benchmark)
But somehow `scipy.minimize` can't correctly minimize the tracking error function, the results just don't make any sense. For other functions like maximizing the return it works flawless.

In the end the two lines should be very similar, but they aren't. Scipy doesn't complain but the results are just not what one would expect, do you know why this objective function troubles scipy?

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def portfolio_te(weights, rets, bm_rets):
    port_returns = np.dot(rets, weights)
    te = np.sqrt(np.mean((port_returns - bm_rets)**2))
    return te

stocks_returns = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 0.02, (250, 10)))
benchmark_returns = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0, 0.02, 250))

result = minimize(portfolio_te, x0=[0.1 for i in range(10)],
        bounds=[(0,0.3) for i in range(10)], method='SLSQP',
        args=(stocks_returns, benchmark_returns))
        
port_returns = pd.Series(np.dot(stocks_returns, result.x))

ts = pd.concat([(1+port_returns).cumprod(), (1+benchmark_returns).cumprod()], axis=1)
ts.plot()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me that there *is* a solution to this problem.

You have 10 stocks that you can pick, which all have random returns. You have an index which is also randomly created. You would expect the correlation between any two sets of random numbers to be nearly zero, and therefore that the match between any portfolio and the benchmark would be fairly poor.

If I change the problem so that it does have a solution, by randomly creating some weights, computing the stock returns given those weights, and then solving for the original weights given those given the stock returns, it works fairly reliably.

```
true_weight = np.random.rand(10)
true_weight /= true_weight.sum()  # Ensure weights sum to 1
stocks_returns = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 0.02, (250, 10)))
benchmark_returns = pd.Series((stocks_returns.values @ true_weight))
```

Now that you know the true weights, you can check if the minimization worked to find them.

```
average_pct_error = np.abs((((result.x - true_weight) / true_weight) * 100)).mean()
print(f"Average portfolio component was wrong from true weight by {average_pct_error:.2f}%")
```

The cumulative return graph also agrees.

I get on the order of 0.1% error when doing this, which you can lower to near zero through the `ftol` option:

```
result = minimize(portfolio_te, x0=[0.1 for i in range(10)],
        bounds=[(0,0.3) for i in range(10)], method='SLSQP',
        options=dict(ftol=1e-10),
        args=(stocks_returns, benchmark_returns))
```

An alternative way to specify the loss function would be to minimize cumulative returns RMSE. This improves the graphs you're making, but I would worry that it over-values matching returns early in the time series vs. matching them later.

Comment: good point, I was just trying to quickly come up with a MWE, didn't think that through and indeed with reasonable input data it works!
Which confuses me even more, because in reality I have a portfolio of 16 stocks and the results are just completely off. When optimizing only the maximum return the output portfolio is actually way closer to the benchmark then when minimizing the Tracking error. But apparently the function seems to work...

Comment: @Quastiat I have two guesses for what might be going wrong: first, it could be that the value of the index or fund you're tracking is being calculated in a slightly different way. For example, this return calculation assumes that the portfolio is continuously rebalanced to keep the weights exactly the same at each time step. But maybe the fund you're tracking actually only buys and sells stocks once a month, so that doesn't match. The second idea is that there could be some noise in your index. I found that adding noise on the order of 30% of the underlying return produced huge errors.

Comment: Thanks for input, I am sure there is no perfect solution to my problem, I just thought there might be a way to find the lowest possible tracking error. The result shouldn't be a 100% match but just as good as possible. Do you know a way to find that portfolio that comes closest other than a linear regression, but minimizing some objective function? I just don't get, even if theres not a 100% solution, why minimizing the tracking error yields totally random results.